# How to modify an external website with Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-webui

I want to load an external website like www.twitter.com in my dom tree and then **modify for example some divs**. How can I do this with Dart?

And even if I change the website f.e. by typing a search request, i should also be able to insert an overlay into the dom tree.

Is it possible with Dart to modify external web pages?

Somehow with an iframe maybe?

```
<iframe src="https://www.twitter.com" width="100%" height="300">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

However I get the error message

```
Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

Comment: That's because of a setting in the response from Twitter because they don't want you to use their content in that way. You can fetch the content using an HTTP request imperatively, modify and add it to the DOM, but you should be aware that you probably violate Twitter's or its users copyright.

Comment: I found an easier way by creating a plugin for a browser such as Chrome where the modification of the DOM-tree is possible :)